# How to print the letter A incrementally in loop in bash?

Tags: bash

I'm learning bash, and I want to print the letter A in the for loop, each time one more than the previous one. So, for example, if I the loop iterates 5 times, I want to have the following output:

```
A
AA
AAA
AAAA
AAAAA
```

I started with something like this, but I don't know how to achieve what I want:

```
#!/bin/bash

INDEX=1

while [ $INDEX -lt 5 ]; do
   echo "??"
done
```

Any ideas to achieve what I want?

Comment: All-caps names are reserved for names with meaning to the shell or operating system, so consider using lower-case names for your own variables; see fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a namespace (which is to say, a shell variable with a name that overlaps with a preexisting environment variable will overwrite the latter).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Append to a string. To take advantage of bash facilities in doing this:

```
for ((index=0; index<5; index++)); do
  s+=A
  echo "$s"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

INDEX=1

while [ $INDEX -lt 6 ]; do 
   for ((i=1;i<=$INDEX;i++)); do
      printf A
   done
   printf "\n"
   INDEX=$(($INDEX+1))
done
```

Comment: Better to use `printf A` or `printf '%s' A` if you're going for POSIX sh, btw -- `echo -n` is undefined. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html; quoting from the first line of the APPLICATION USAGE section: ""It is not possible to use echo portably across all POSIX systems unless both -n (as the first argument) and escape sequences are omitted.""

Comment: Also, `$[ ... ]` is actually pre-POSIX math syntax -- the POSIX sh spec removes it in favor of `$(( ... ))`, making it pure Bourne backwards compatibility.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you for the constructive comments :) .. I will change it accordingly

Comment: @CharlesDuffy updated my answer ... please let me know if there is any thing I have missed